# Is there an API in SwaggerHub to update the file definition?

Tags: swaggerhub

Is there an API to update the file definition?
I am looking for a way to keep my project in Git and SwaggerHub in sync automatically, so I would like to update the file definition at every merge.
Is it possible? How do you manage keeping your project and SwaggerHub definition in sync automatically?

Comment: Is your question about SwaggerHub by any chance?

Comment: Yes i am going to update my post.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, SwaggerHub has an API:

https://api.swaggerhub.com
[Integrating with the SwaggerHub API](https://swagger.io/blog/api-development/integrating-with-the-swaggerhub-api/)

and a number of official API clients.

### API

cURL command to create or update an API (note the use of `--data-binary` instead of `-d/--data`):

```
curl -X POST "https://api.swaggerhub.com/apis/OWNER/API_NAME" \
     -H "Authorization: YOUR_API_KEY" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/yaml" \
     --data-binary @myapi.yaml
```

Raw HTTP request for the reference:

```
POST https://api.swaggerhub.com/apis/OWNER/API_NAME
Authorization: YOUR_API_KEY
Content-Type: application/yaml

# Request body is your complete YAML/JSON file
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  title: My API
  version: 1.0.0
paths:
  ...
```

Use the correct `Content-Type` header value: `application/yaml` for YAML or `application/json` for JSON.

### SwaggerHub CLI

A [command-line wrapper](https://github.com/SmartBear/swaggerhub-cli) around the SwaggerHub API, available as a npm module.

```
npm install -g swaggerhub-cli
```

Specify your API key (get it from https://app.swaggerhub.com/settings/apiKey):

```
swaggerhub configure

? SwaggerHub URL: https://api.swaggerhub.com
? API Key: <paste your key>
```

Create a new API:

```
swaggerhub api:create OWNER/API_NAME --file myapi.yaml
```

Update an existing API:

```
swaggerhub api:update OWNER/API_NAME/VERSION --file myapi.yaml --visibility private
```

### Maven plugin

https://github.com/swagger-api/swaggerhub-maven-plugin/

### Gradle plugin

https://github.com/swagger-api/swaggerhub-gradle-plugin/