# SwaggerHub error 500 during update API definitions

Tags: rest, postman, http-status-code-500, swaggerhub

I tried to update my API's  swagger definition on  SwaggerHub mock server. For test i download swagger file from https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json. And try to send POST request to swaggerhub.com/apis/was_mock/uber_private.

Where {owner} = was_mock  and {api} = uber_private.

Also  i added to header "Authorization" and my secret key. File attached as "form-data" with name "definition".

When i send request - I received following exception

```
{
    "code": 500,
    "message": "There was an error processing your request. It has been logged (ID: 25c6ad4735c99ccd)"
}
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an API in SwaggerHub to update the file definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52650853/is-there-an-api-in-swaggerhub-to-update-the-file-definition)

Comment: The request format is not correct - see the ^^ linked question for the correct format. Specifically, the `Content-Type` must be `application/json` and the request body must be the contents of the JSON file.