# How to automatically update API documentation in SwaggerHub?

Tags: .net-core, openapi, swaggerhub

I'm using .NET Core app and want to automatically generate OpenAPI documentation in SwaggerHub whenever I push code to a branch in GitHub, so that I can share it across teams. Manually I can run the project, open the Swagger link in a browser, copy the API documentation and paste it in SwaggerHub. But I want to automate this process so that just by pushing code to a branch in GitHub, the API documentation is updated in SwaggerHub.

Comment: SwaggerHub has an [API to update hosted definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52661431/113116) programmatically. If your app build process produces an OpenAPI YAML/JSON file, you could just add an extra step to upload that file to SwaggerHub.